# I've imported data from web in excel. When I try to use the AVERAGE formula, I get the #DIV/0! error and I dont know how to fix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I imported a table from web, and I wanted to start looking at MIN, MAX, AVERAGE, STDV etc.  But I've encountered a problem with formulas always popping up as errors?  And Im not sure how to fix this or what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

I've attempted changing the values of the table to 'numbers' instead of 'general'

I also attempted to use `AVERAGEA` instead of just `AVERAGE` and that resulted in 0.00

Im not really sure what to try next

Answer (score 0):

Your column is formatted as text. Format it to numbers or use `VALUE` formula inside: `=AVERAGE(VALUE(K2:K15))`